# How to get the column value (stored in XML)

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In our table some column is simple and some column have data in XML format (stored in Map as entry key). How to fetch the both column values. And EmployeeDetails column value also we need to show as column.

- New Column result should be like below in select query

*EmployeeID,departmentID,displayName,email,firstname,lastname,jobCode*

```
------------------Sample value in existing column----------
EmployeeID
=======
11
12
13
14
----------------
EmployeeDetails
================
<Attributes>
  <Map> 
    <entry key="departmentID" value="22290"/>
    <entry key="displayName" value="Testcb45, usrcb45 "/>
    <entry key="email" value="uTestc23@testt.com"/>
     <entry key="lastname" value="Testcb45"/>
    <entry key="firstname" value="usrcb45"/>
    <entry key="fullName" value="usrcb45 Testcb45"/>
    <entry key="jobCode" value="985512"/>
  </Map>
</Attributes>
```

I have tried below query but getting exception and EmployeeDetails Column name in our table is "attributes" and in below query I am fetching the details only from the XML column

```
declare @src nvarchar(max);
set @src =
(select attributes from spt_identity_snapshot where identity_name='20000145')
;with x as
(
    select  cast(@src as xml) as attributes
)
select 
      email.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as email
    , employeeId.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as employeeId
    , firstName.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as firstName
    , lastName.s.value('.', 'nvarchar(max)') as lastName
from x
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "email"]/@value') email(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "employeeId"]/@value') employeeId(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "firstName"]/@value') firstName(s)
    CROSS APPLY attributes.nodes('//entry[@key = "lastName"]/@value') lastName(s);
```

After executing above query I am getting below error. Because this single user have 3 row in the table.

> We encountered an error while trying to connect.
> Details: "Microsoft SQL: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: I am unable to paste the query in reply. But when I am using my query then its showing below exception-   We encountered an error while trying to connect.
 Details: "Microsoft SQL: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression."

Comment: [edit] your query and exception into the question.

Comment: Hi Dale, Updated the question section, please check.

Comment: If I am executing the query for user who have single row in table then its returning the result. But if user have multiple row in table then its throwing exception. I have fetched the data only for the XML column in query but later I will include the EmployeeID column also in query.